# using mongoDB find() in express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, find

I was trying to check if a person had already applied for a job, so for that I used find() method to get the documents with the job Id and user ID I'm passing in, but it's always posting the data, not checking if those already exist?

here is the code,

```
router.post('/', async(req,res)=>{
   const count = Apply.find({user:req.body.user, job:req.body.job}).count()
    
  if(count>0){
    return res.status(400).send('already applied')
  }
 else{
  let apply = new Apply({
        job :req.body.job,
        user :req.body.user
        
    })

    apply = await apply.save();
    if(!apply)
    return res.status(400).send('cannot apply')
    res.send(apply);
 }
   
})
```

each request is getting ,

```
POST /api/v1/applys/ 200 141 - 58.007 ms
```

I dont have much idea about using find(), so can't figure out the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

since you're using async/await add await before Apply.find

```
const count = await Apply.find({user:req.body.user, job:req.body.job}).count()
```

Comment: You're welcome, you can also try using create instead of new and save like this
const apply = await Apply.create({ job: req.body.job, user: req.body.user })

Comment: I will try that